# Force MongoDB to store 0 values with C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with C# and have run into a problem in that if I send an object to store in mongo, any integer values that = 0 are not stored.

For example, if I had a class like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created an instance with the values x = 1 and y = 0 and stored it in mongo, the result would be:

```
{
    "x" : 1
}
```

whereas what I want is:

```
{
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 0
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something because I'm unable to find anyone else having a problem with this.

The reason I need the 0 value is because I need to use it with a mongo aggregation function.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you at least show us the relevant part of your code where you do the update?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm just using the Insert function from the mongo driver: Collection.Insert(data);

Comment: Wanted to know how you are populating the data object so that I can suggest an alternative like `var data = new BsonDocument().Add("x", 1).Add("y", 0);Entity.Save(data);`

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce what you are reporting. I created a test program using your Data class and stored a document in MongoDB like this:

```
var document = new Data { x = 1, y = 0 };
collection.Insert(document);
```

I then used the MongoDB shell to see what was inserted in to the database:

```
> db.data.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550c7542f266222543e1d16d"), "x" : 1, "y" : 0 }
>
```

And it did store y with a value of 0.

Have you configured any conventions that might be overriding how 0 values are serialized?

Answer (score 0):

You can register class map for your Data class as below to instruct mongodb to store default value for y.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Data>( cm => 
{
   cm.AutoMap();
   cm.MapMember(d => d.y).SetIgnoreIfDefault(false);
});
```